# Unfolding non-empty structures to lists

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes, corecursion

I want to write `Foldable.toList` for a non-empty rose tree using an anamorphism, but it seems impossible to extract the last element:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

data RoseTree a = RoseNode a [RoseTree a]

ana5 :: RoseTree a -> [a]
ana5 = ana coalg5

coalg5 :: RoseTree a -> ListF a (RoseTree a)
coalg5 (RoseNode a []) = Nil
coalg5 (RoseNode a (RoseNode b1 b2:t)) = Cons a $ RoseNode b1 (b2 ++ t)
```

Is it indeed impossible and does it generalize to all non-empty structures?

Also (it's sort of an optional bonus question) is there a general rule to determine when `Fix f -> Fix g` can be implemented using f-algebras but not g-coalgebras?

Btw apomorphism worked:

```
coalg6 (RoseNode a []) = Cons a $ Left []
coalg6 (RoseNode a (RoseNode b1 b2:t)) = Cons a $ Right $ RoseNode b1 (b2 ++ t)
```

`apo coalg6` has the same type as `ana5` but doesn't lose one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've answered your own question: this operation is naturally structured as an apomorphism, not an anamorphism.

You can, of course, implement `apo` in terms of `ana`:

```
apo :: Functor f => (a -> f (Either (Fix f) a)) -> a -> Fix f
apo f = ana (either (fmap Left . unFix) f) . Right
```

(I came up with this by dualising "`para` in terms of `cata`": `para f = snd . cata (Fix . fmap fst &&& f)`.)

You can just plug your `coalg6` into this and get a coalgebra which does the same thing when given to `ana`:

```
ana5 = ana coalg5 . Right
    where coalg5 = either (fmap Left . unFix) coalg6
```